# Which is the most efficient way to compare values in 2 different MySQL database?

Tags: c#, mysql

I made an app in c#, that transfer the data from a database (MySQL 5.5), to another(MySQL 5.7) with a different schema. I need to check that the data transfered is consistent with the data in the original database, i.e., the number of imported records must be the same and all the values must be the same. So besides writing a huge unit test in which i compare record by record, is there an efficient (or simplier way) to do that?

Comment: Could you run it twice - from database 1 to 2 then back to 1. Then compare the original data in database 1 to the new data (presumably in new tables). If they match - you are good to go. _It doesn't **guarantee** database 2 is correct, but the likelihood of their being a bug that only occurs on the first copy and not the second seems low._

Comment: This would have been a good idea if it wasn't for the fact that i need pratically to build another application to do the opposite process, and it's far more expensive to do.

Comment: The tool you ran to copy from 1 to 2 - couldn't you use the same tool to copy from 2 back to 1?

Comment: No because the tool (DTO and DAO) used to build tables and data in db2 simply don't exist for db1.

Comment: The question is not if there´s something different than a unit-test, as a unit-test is just some *tool* to test. It doesn´t tell you *what* to test. So the answer to your question is: you have to write some code that *tests* that both databases contain valid values. If you´re doing this with unit-test actually or in your own app won´t make a huge difference though.

Comment: To be 100% certain you need to validate each record...  If you want a high degree of confidence you can run an aggregate such as a sum or count on each involved table.  Also use the statistics that you can obtain from the sync queries such as number of rows affected to gain some insight into the scope of touched data.

Comment: You can always use a product like Sql Data Compare. There is [obviously] an associated cost though. Maybe they have a trial version or something you can use... :-)

Comment: Haven't tried, but how about doing a mysqldump of each database and then using diff to see the differences. The data should be fairly the same.

Comment: @JacquesAmar The 2 databases have different schemas so it can't work. I'm using NicoE approach

Comment: @DanieleSartori, with mysqldump, you can just specify the tables you are interested in. But I also like a statistical approach.